# how to set value using xml.dom.minidom python

Tags: python, xml

I having a variable `c` that has value `"test"` I tried to assign that value to the `Cookie` attribute by using `xml.dom.minidom` in python. I tried following code:

```
l='<Lg Cookie=""/>'
dom = parseString(l)

L=dom.getElementsByTagName('Lg')[0]
lgs = L.setAttribute("Cookie",c)

print lgs
```

Not giving anything; expected output:

```
l='<Lg Cookie="test"/>'
```

Comment: Side note: Is it really that much easier to write `o/p` instead of `output`? I edited that, since I doubt a sizeable portion of programmers can immediately understand the short form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setAttribute`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.setAttribute) doesn't return anything, it just changes the value. You want to print the [XML representation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml) of the node itself:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
l = '<Lg Cookie=""/>'
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(l)
L = dom.getElementsByTagName('Lg')[0]
L.setAttribute('Cookie', 'test')
print (L.toxml())
```